# Image transition animation on ribbon button

Tags: wpf, ribbon

How can I create a WPF ribbon button switching between two images, with an animated "wipe" transition between images? I can't place both images within a a grid within the button and animate the opacity of each image in turn (as suggested [here](http://learnwpf.com/post/2006/10/03/How-can-I-create-a-e2809cwipee2809d-effect-to-transition-between-two-images-in-WPF.aspx)) because I can't set the content of the ribbon directly, only the `LargeImageSource`/`SmallImageSource` and `Label` properties.

**Update**

I tried BorisB.'s suggestion together with the animation from the link above, but there is now no image displayed in the ribbon button. Removing the animation, opacity mask and multiple images, and leaving the following code also doesn't show the image at all.

```
<RibbonToggleButton Label="Dashboard" Name="btnDashboard" IsChecked="True">
  <RibbonToggleButton.LargeImageSource>
    <DrawingImage>
      <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
          <ImageDrawing ImageSource="/Icons/Dashboard.png" />
        </DrawingGroup>
      </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
  </RibbonToggleButton.LargeImageSource>
</RibbonToggleButton>
```

Comment: What ribbon are you using? What is the type of LargeItemSource/SmallItemSource properties?

Comment: @BorisB. `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`, using the built-in Ribbon in .NET 4.5

Comment: You can try assigning a DrawingImage as a source, and then assigning a DrawingGroup as a DrawingImage.Drawing. That drawing group can contain two ImageDrawings so you could apply the approach from your link.

Comment: @BorisB. Thanks, but I tried this, with the results described in my edited question.

Comment: Provide the Rect property of the ImageDrawing: `<ImageDrawing Rect="0, 0, 32, 32" ImageSource=...>`. It would show the image, but it doesn't help you since the code in the link you provided relies on OpacityMask for the effect, and OpacityMask can only be applied to a UIElement or a Visual and not on a Drawing as it seems.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37015/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-boris-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DrawingImage` as an ImageSource. Then you can assign a `DrawingGroup` as a `DrawingImage.Drawing`. That drawing group can contain two `ImageDrawing`s wrapped in their own `DrawingGroup`s, so you could apply the approach from your link:

```
<Grid>
    <Ribbon>
        <RibbonTab x:Name="HomeTab" Header="Home">
            <RibbonGroup x:Name="Group1" Header="Group1">
                <RibbonButton x:Name="Button1" Label="Button1">
                    <RibbonButton.LargeImageSource>
                        <DrawingImage>
                            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                <DrawingGroup>
                                    <DrawingGroup>
                                        <ImageDrawing Rect="0, 0, 32, 32" ImageSource=ImageOne.png"/>
                                    </DrawingGroup>
                                    <DrawingGroup>
                                        <ImageDrawing Rect="0, 0, 32, 32" ImageSource="ImageTwo.png"/>
                                        <DrawingGroup.OpacityMask>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black" x:Name="BlackStop"/>
                                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent" x:Name="TransparentStop"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </DrawingGroup.OpacityMask>
                                    </DrawingGroup>
                                </DrawingGroup>
                            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                        </DrawingImage>
                    </RibbonButton.LargeImageSource>
                </RibbonButton>
            </RibbonGroup>
        </RibbonTab>
    </Ribbon>
</Grid>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TransparentStop" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" By="1"  Duration="0:0:2"   />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BlackStop" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" By="1" Duration="0:0:2" 
                         BeginTime="0:0:0.05" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

The wrapping DrawingGroups are used so you can use OpacityMask, which is essential for the effect.

Comment: A minor point, but the first `ImageDrawing` doesn't need to be wrapped in a `DrawingGroup`.